# inconsistency between nltk stanford ner tagger and stanford ner tagger online demo

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using python's inbuilt library nltk to get stanford ner tagger api setup but i am seeing inconsistency between tagging of words by this api and online demo on stanford's ner tagger website.Some words are being tagged in online demo while they are not being in api in python and similarly some words are being tagged differently.I have used the same classifiers as mentioned in the website. Can anyone tell me why is the problem coming and what's the solution for it..?

Comment: What version of CoreNLP are you using? We occasionally update the models between releases. Otherwise, there are occasional tiebreaking differences between machines.

Comment: I found the same thing as Sarthak. In particular, I noticed that the title before a person's name (e.g. the "Mr." in Mr. Jones) was NOT flagged as part of an entity in the version I am using (3.7.0, downloaded 2/28/17 from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml#Download), but it IS flagged in the online demo. I would like the titles to be flagged. Is it possible to get the in-between releases on Github or elsewhere? (I am using the 7-class model).

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue and determined that my code and the online demo were applying different formatting rules for the text.

https://github.com/dat/pyner/blob/master/ner/client.py

```
for s in ('\f', '\n', '\r', '\t', '\v'): #strip whitespaces
            text = text.replace(s, '')
        text += '\n' #ensure end-of-line
```